# Can a type inside a lambda parameter list refer to an uncaptured outer variable?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr, scoping

I'm trying to use `std::size` instead of macros like `_countof` or `ARRAYSIZE`, but I'm running into scoping problems.

Is the following code legal?

```
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int arr1[4];
    auto f = [](int(&arr2)[std::size(arr1)])
    {
        arr2[0] = 1;
    };
    (void)arr1;
    (void)f;
}
```

GCC and MSVC compile it fine, but Clang [complains](https://godbolt.org/z/q6rrfTG1E):

```
error: variable 'arr1' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
    auto f = [](int(&arr2)[std::size(arr1)])
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: clang is wrong, arr1 is not captured because it is not evaluated. define a separate `constexpr auto size_arr1 = std::size(arr1);` and then use it in the lambda to convince clang

Comment: @n.m. `std::size(arr1)` does not appear in an unevaluated operand, so it is potentially-evaluated and `arr1` is odr-used. I think the question is rather whether or not the odr-use is allowed in the parameter of the lambda (with or without implicit/explicit capture).

Comment: @n.m.: What about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8dh8PaTP4)?

Comment: you are right I was not reading it carefully enough.

Comment: There are no errors with clang 16. I also tried with c++2a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Clang is correct.

(Using terminology from the current C++23 draft.)

`std::size(arr1)` is not part of an unevaluated operand, so the expression `arr1` is a potentially-evaluated id-expression naming the variable `arr1`. The expression is also not part of a discarded-value expression, nor is the variable `arr1` usable in constant expressions. Therefore the expression odr-uses `arr1`. (The variable could be made usable in constant expressions, making `arr1` not an odr-use, by adding `constexpr` on it.)

However, being a variable with automatic storage duration, `arr1` is a local entity that is not odr-usable in the scope in which the expression appears. Specifically, to be odr-usable inside a lambda a local entity must be captured by the lambda, which `arr1` is not. Even with a capture however, [CWG 2380](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2380.html) clarifies that the local entity is odr-usable only in the block scope of the lambda, not in the function parameter declaration clause.

A program that odr-uses a local enitity in a scope in which it isn't odr-usable is ill-formed.